# AdMob banner ad not showing

Tags: android, admob, ads

I am using admob in my app, it was working fine but suddenly it stopped showing ads at all.
Bellow is my codes i used:

mainActivity.xml:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

MainActivity.java

```
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

AndroidManifest:

```
 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  

<!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

I followed all the instructions from adMob site as i said it was working few days ago.

Bellow are few line from logcat which may be related to my issue:

```
09-25 22:44:50.292: E/dalvikvm(18554): Could not find class 'android.app.AppOpsManager', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zza
```

---

```
09-25 22:45:07.209: E/Ads(18554): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderAd is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
09-25 22:45:07.209: E/Web Console(18554): Uncaught ReferenceError: renderAd is not defined:1
09-25 22:45:07.209: E/Ads(18554): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
09-25 22:45:07.209: E/Web Console(18554): Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined:1
```

---

I get bellow warning repeatedly and it appears more when i click the blank area where ad should be showing

```
09-25 22:46:10.911: W/PicturePileLayerContent(18554): Warning: painting PicturePile without content!
```

---

This is filtered logcat with "ads"

```
09-25 23:39:25.948: I/Ads(28874): Starting ad request.
09-25 23:39:25.948: I/Ads(28874): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("8FCD71CAAE776558876AAA9BA964245A") to get test ads on this device.

09-25 23:39:26.919: I/Ads(22050): App index is not enabled
09-25 23:39:30.432: E/Ads(28874): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderAd is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
09-25 23:39:30.442: E/Ads(28874): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
09-25 23:39:30.442: I/Ads(28874): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
09-25 23:39:30.472: I/Ads(28874): Ad finished loading.
```

I have searched everywhere for the solution and also looked at some similar but non of them helped me.

Comment: i get this error after adding builder().addTestDevice("******") `09-26 14:26:49.691: E/Ads(28853): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: renderAd is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
09-26 14:26:49.701: E/Ads(28853): JS: Uncaught ReferenceError: onLoad is not defined (https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/mads/gma:1)
`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This problem is solved by uninstalling the app manually and reinstalling again without making any changes!!

Comment: It works! Your question was not about testing, right?

Answer (score 18):

Use below lines of code

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);

AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
.addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // My Galaxy Nexus test phone
.build();


mAdView.loadAd(request );
```

instead of using this

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

because this line will be used when your application would be ready for publish on Google Play Store.

You can place your device's id in place of **"AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4"**. Code to get device id:

```
String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),
            Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

**Please read these carefully:**

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting#test_ads

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

**See this**

[image]

[image]

Comment: i tried your code, it removed this lines from logcat ` 09-25 23:39:25.948: I/Ads(28874): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("8FCD71F44FG4H6D7DAAA9BA964245A") to get test ads on this device` , but ad still not showing!!!

Comment: Google has requested to not use that code (you have used previously) when your app is in development mode. May be your add id has been dismissed. Try some other email and create another add request.

Comment: But I was using default adUnitId which was provided in instructions, I have not used the original adUnitId provide to me.

Comment: I read the "getting started" guid again , it clearly says that the adUnitID given in example is testing purposes and it will retrive test ad, in last step it is mentioned that after loading ad with AdRequest.bhuilder().build(); I will start getting test ads. what i see in 2nd FAQ is  **How do I get test ads?**
_The ad unit and samples that we provide return test ads._ You can also request test ads by using AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice.

Comment: Listen integrating adds in android is only 30 minutes task.. I don't know what are you reading from these tutorial.

Comment: Yes I know it is 30 min task and I setup admob very easily, it was successfully showing test ads, I dont know why it stopped showing ads now.

Comment: Try with other email account

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have latest versions of adMob and GooglePlayServices lib.

Comment: I just added Google play services which shows Rev. 26, i dont know about adMob version there is no instruction for this lib on official site.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the ad didnt show up until I gave enough room for it.

Before it was like

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/primary"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dip">
           <ImageView
                android:onClick="goBack"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_white_48dp"
                android:layout_width="50dip"
                android:layout_height="50dip"/>
           <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/dwn_bnr_ad"/>
```

Here the adview is having height of wrap_content, so it adjusts itself to achieve its height, but its parent (LinearLayout) has a strict height of 90dip which doesnt allow the adView to take enough space to display ads.

So what I did was just changed the height of the LinearLayout to wrap_content then things got fine

Answer (score 0):

Put the banner in a LinearLayout just as this ,i faced the same problem and i fixed it by puting it in a linear layout

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8056472942589154/2652831823"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/saida"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` is not valid attribute of LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you go back to your admob account to register your specific app for ads and get a new longer publisher number with the 'ca-app-pub-' preface instead of the 'pub-' preface?

Nowhere in the "banner ads 1" instructions on the Google Admob "Google Mobile Ads SDK" development site does it mention having to go back to your admob account to do this.

This stupid mistake held me up for days.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the code below under the `buildscript` section of the project level `build.gradle`

Make sure `maven {url "https://maven.google.com"}` is under `allProjects > repositories`:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure that you have added `Banner Ad Unit` in your Admob Account
>   and used banner `appUnit-id` in your adUnitId of your app where Banner Ads are displayed .

Answer (score 0):

One of reasons is that your device is not configured as device test : https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9691433